# How to reverse sort again after sort an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vue.js

I'm doing a list of items by using a v-for and for each properties i'm trying to sort them by ascending and descending.

The fact is I trigger the sort function on a v-btn to sort by ascending but when i click again nothing happen. I would like to reverse the sort and etc. when I click again on it.

My current method for on of my property is :

```
sortByScope()
      {
        this.alerts.sort(function(a, b){
            if(a.scope < b.scope){ return -1 }
            if(a.scope > b.scope){ return 1 }
            return 0
        })
      },
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: you mean like this solutione? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50503194/4173464

Comment: wow ! I thought i searched in all Stack topics but you nailed it ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your button to sort ascending or descending based on the current sorting of the column. You can do so by using a toggle flag:

```js
sortByScope() {
  this.alerts.sort(function (a, b) {
    return this.sortScopeToggle
      ? a - b
      : b - a;
  });
  this.sortScopeToggle = !this.sortScopeToggle;
}
```

Where `sortScopeToggle` is a boolean that keeps track of the sorting order, and based on this boolean, a [ternary operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) returns the sorting algorithm.

Comment: Why not only one handler and within the handler use the ternary condition?

Comment: `this.alerts.sort((a, b) => this.sortScopeToggle ? (a - b) : (b - a));`

Comment: I have several properties to sort and @db1975 redirect me to an other topic with is exactly what i needed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50503194/4173464). With one method and with using a computed one it work like a charm.